# What simple weapons can the "Scorching Weapon" feat be applied to?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, feats, weapons

In creating my Ifrit Sorcerer, I am wondering if the feat *Scorching Weapon* would be of any use to me.

This part of its text [from its page on d20pfsrd](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/racial-feats/scorching-weapons-combat-ifrit) seems ambiguous:

> As a swift action, you can make up to two held manufactured metallic weapons become red-hot for 1 round, dealing 1 additional point of fire damage with a successful hit.

I assume the intent was for sword or maces, but those often have non-metal components.  Spears and darts could also fall into that category.

Are there any ranged, simple weapons that my Sorcerer could use with this feat, or is this feat simply a stepping stone to Inner Flame, or Blazing Aura in my case?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

All of the simple weapons. *Maybe* even ammunition weapons, because the ammunition might not be the weapon, but even a red-hot crossbow will make metal ammunition pretty hot, though there lies debate.

There's actually two ambiguities here, both of which totally work in your favour.

## 1. Pathfinder never says what weapons are composed of

You might picture a spear as wooden pole tipped with a metal blade, but there's actually nothing saying it has to be that way. Not on the whole [weapons](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/equipment---final/weapons) page or the [spear](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/equipment---final/weapons/weapon-descriptions/spear) description does it specify what your spear has to be made from. It could be metal, spectacularly tough wood, stone or other materials - and it could be a mix of materials, or one solid piece. It might even be a very sturdy origami construction (paper cuts — the worst!). In any of those cases, it's still your typical 1d8 spear.

The same goes for other weapons too - [longspear](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/equipment---final/weapons/weapon-descriptions/longspear), [club](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/equipment---final/weapons/weapon-descriptions/club), [longsword](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/equipment---final/weapons/weapon-descriptions/longsword), [mace](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/equipment---final/weapons/weapon-descriptions/mace-heavy), [darts](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/equipment---final/weapons/weapon-descriptions/ammunition/ammunition-thrown-darts), they can all be made from whatever mundane materials you want in whatever composition (including solid metal) and still fit the bill. The exception is the [wooden stake](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/equipment---final/weapons/weapon-descriptions/stake-wooden), which is kinda defeating the point if you make it out of anything else.

When you think about it, this doesn't even just apply to basic weapons. Presumably your mithril sword has a mithril blade, but is the whole thing mithril - haft and pommel too? If not, what's the rest made from?

## 2. Scorching Weapon doesn't say much on what counts as "metallic" nor how the weapon's heated

All [metallic means](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/metallic) is "made of metal" or "has metal in it". Your spear counts as metallic whether it has a metal tip or it's metal throughout, and your spear could be either. It doesn't stop being metallic if it has non-metal components. If it has a stone haft, it might be relatively *less* metal, but the important pokey bit is no less metal for it.

The feat has boiling-blood flavour, but whatever's going on there is kinda magical, and it doesn't say your super-hot blood is what's making your weapon red hot. If you're *magically* heating up your weapon, I don't see a problem with *magically* making just the metal part red-hot even when the part you're holding isn't metal. That's still going to hurt a bit more when you poke someone with it - the haft doesn't need to be red-hot too.

## So: you can heat up ALL THE WEAPONS!    _o\

Just make sure the bit you'll be hurting people with is made of metal. If you're really concerned, and want to make sure the boiling-blood flavour works for you, make a request to the blacksmith to build the whole thing out of metal.

Except the [wooden stake](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/equipment---final/weapons/weapon-descriptions/stake-wooden).

Answer (score 2):

Looking through Ultimate Equipment I see the following:

### Definitely Metal Simple Weapons:

- Bayonet
- Brass knuckles
- Dagger
- Gauntlet
- Light and Heavy Mace
- Punching Dagger
- Spiked Gauntlet

### Possibly Metal or Partially Metal

- Battle Aspergilium
- Dart
- Javelin
- Morningstar
- Sickle

### Not Very Metal

- Cestus
- Spears

Hope this helps. If it was my game, I'd definitely allow it on the first group, and probably on the second group. You may also have to pay extra or have a slightly reduced range increment and increased weight for an all-metal version. You'd have to make a good argument for the third and possibly pay a little extra for the weapon.

Comment: I may ask the DM about metal Javelins (for extra cost of course).  I don't want my sorcerer anywhere near getting smacked in the face at level 1.

Comment: @DavidWilkins Just remember that thrown weapons are destroyed / rendered unusable on a hit. This could get expensive quickly if you are paying 2-3gp per throw. Also if a regular Javelin is 2 lbs, a metal one may be 3-5 lbs. Sorcerers are not known for their carrying capacity...

Comment: Very true, but it would only be for the first level or two, while I build up my spell list.  At the same time, our party might be big enough that me having downtime wouldn't be detrimental.  This information definitely helps though, in case I consider a Ifrit monk in the future.

Comment: Ifrits with -2 WIS don't make the best monks. If you want ranged, try metal sling bullets or all metal crossbow bolts. It depends on your GM's definition of what it means to be a "held metallic weapon". Also, it is just a single point of extra damage; consider the costs and benefits. You don't have access to the other feats until 7th level. So a heated javelin will do 1d6 + 1 +/- STR damage and cost you 2-5gp per throw. Ray of frost will deal 1d3 damage and you can use it an infinite number of times for free.

Comment: @DavidWilkins Red_Shadow is applying the rules for ammunition to thrown weapons. [While ammunition is destroyed on a successful hit (and half the time on a miss), thrown weapons aren't.](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/equipment---final/weapons#exotic-ammo) That steel javelin just needs to be recovered--not repaired--after it's thrown.

Comment: @Red_Shadow I wouldn't consider ammunition to be a "held weapon", and yes it would be costly, but something to use as a last resort if all my spell slots are gone and I somehow cannot use cantrips.

Comment: @HeyICanChan I don't think there is a specific rule about thrown weapons being recoverable, but I have read that reasonable logic should apply.  That said, a steel javelin could be bent, rendering it broken.

Comment: @DavidWilkins It's probably true that the rules *don't* say that weapons *don't* break on a hit or break half the time on a miss, but that doesn't mean the rules *for ammunition* (which explicitly *do* break on a hit and break half the time on a miss) apply to *all weapons.*